# Tensorflow SeparableConv2D training so slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I tried to replace the Conv2D layers in my model with SeparableConv2D layers - direct drop in replacement with everything else in the architecture the same. I do notice a reduction of 3x in model parameters, which is what I need. However, the training time per epoch doubles.
I am using Tensorflow 2.9

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv2D() --> tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D()
```

What could be the cause of this? Is there a way around this?

Thank you.

Comment: According to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12132#issuecomment-584414540) thread, this could be due to an outdated cuDNN version. Which one are you using?

Comment: When running training, it says this before epoch 1 starts: Loaded cuDNN version 8101. It is running inside a Docker container though